# Moving rows with NSFetchedResultsController (Swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, reloaddata

Why exactly doesn't this work? When the tableview reloads data, the objects move to their original position

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    var objects = myFetchRC.fetchedObjects!

    let object = myFetchRC.object(at: sourceIndexPath)
    objects.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    objects.insert(object, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()

    tableView.reloadData()


}
```

EDIT: moving the reload data function to after the save context does not solve the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping `tableView.reloadData()` and `CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()`.

Core Data only fully commits your changes when you save the managed object context, so when the tableView reloads, you are likely still getting the old ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an extremely knuckle-headed solution.

First a new sort descriptor, a Double attribute called "index":

```
myFetch.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "tripName", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "index", ascending: true)]
```

Every time a new object is created the index is incremented in an ascending order. Then in the moveRowAt function I added this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if sourceIndexPath > destinationIndexPath{
        myFetchRC.object(at: sourceIndexPath).index = myFetchRC.object(at: destinationIndexPath).index - 0.01
    } else{
        myFetchRC.object(at: sourceIndexPath).index = myFetchRC.object(at: destinationIndexPath).index + 0.01
    }
    
    CoreDataStack.shared.saveContext()
    tableView.reloadData()
    
}
```

This is an extremely ugly solution, and I'm sure it's prone to bugs, but it seems to work. If someone else has the proper solution please let me know!!